# SMTP mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver

Tags: smtp

Error:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in
```

Configuration:

```
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from =
```

Comment: try `nmap localhost` and output the result

Comment: is your windows box listening on port 25 ?

Comment: <?php
mail ('morzi.34@mail.bg', 'Hello!', 'Hello, this is test email', 'From : morzi.34@mail.bg');
?>

Comment: is there a mail-server installed on this windows box? and is it listening on port 25 ?

Comment: its not instaled because i dont know i want some mail server help me please

Comment: check this one http://www.hmailserver.com/index.php?page=download

Answer (score 0):

you need to install a mail server on your windows box.

A free mail server that I recommand is http://www.hmailserver.com/index.php?page=download

Windows Server 2003 has a built-in POP3/SMTP mail server
The Microsoft solution is, of course, Exchange.